# why gdb even step into memcpy and other system functions?

Tags: c, linux, debugging, gdb

I complied my program with only `-g` option, and add some libs like `-lpthread`

But when I use gdb to debug my program, using step it will step into some system functions, like `fork` and `memcpy`.

Is there a way to avoid that? It happens after I install `valgrind` on my computer.

Kernel:2.6.38-13

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run the following from a gdb prompt..

```
(gdb) set auto-solib-add off
```

It prevents gdb from loading symbols from libraries.